# Mysql query count issue including blank strings

Tags: mysql

Hello i am trying to count tracking numbers with non null non empty string in mysql

i see that count won't include null values. But is there a way to make it not include '' empty strings as well?

Thank you.

-Brendon

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it will skip both NULL (which count doesn't count anyway) as well as empty string:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE
WHERE column_name != '' and column_name IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: mysql seems to count NULLs as well unless you specify COUNT(column_name) but yeah this query looks right!

Comment: COUNT() counts rows returned, so it should count if no rows return, so if you remove COUNT() and just call the query with ``*`` you should see how many rows return, this is the COUNT() result.

Comment: I also thought you needed a TRIM(column_name) just in case when column_name is `'    '` but apparently, you don't.